# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} (1+x)^{y/x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} (1+x)^{y/x}$

I have strong belief that this limit exists as I tried some basic lines ($y=2,y=x+2$), and they both gave me the form $1^\infty$

So I tried doing this.

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} (1+x)^{y/x}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} e^{(y/x)\ln(1+x)}$$

and here I am stuck. Evaluating the limit directly would give something like $e^{(2/0)\ln(1)}=e^{(\infty)(0)}$ which is still intederminate.

Comment: $\lim_\limits {x\to 0} (1+x)^{\frac 1x} = e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}\frac{y\ln(1+x)}{x}
$$
which is easy, because by standard theorems on limits
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}\frac{y\ln(1+x)}{x}=
\Bigl(\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}y\Bigr)
\Bigl(\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}\Bigr)=
2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}=2
$$
Then your limit is $e^2$, because the exponential is continuous.

Comment: Can you conclude this? $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)}\frac{y\ln(1+x)}{x} = 2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}$$ You're just taking the limit along the line $y= 2$, which is not the only way you can approach $(0,2)$.

Comment: @mechanodroid Multiplication is continuous. I added the steps.

Comment: I get it, thanks. But then since exponentiation is also continuous, we could have calculated it directly: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} (1+x)^{\frac yx} = \left(\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} (1+x)^{\frac1x}\right)^{\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,2)} y} = \left(\lim_{x\to 0}\, (1+x)^{\frac1x}\right)^{2}= e^2$$

Comment: @mechanodroid Yes, but I prefer to avoid those complications.